# Pine-Script doesn't generate orders

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, algorithmic-trading

I got ChatGPT to write me this strategy for TradingView, but it won't generate any orders to backtest. Can I change it so it works? It doesn't put out an syntax-error and there is enough data and paper-money to open positions, so I don't understand where the problem is... thanks in advance

```
//@version=5
strategy("20-Day High and ATR Add to Position", overlay=true)

// Calculate 20-day high
high20Days = ta.highest(high, 20)

// Calculate ATR
atrValue = ta.atr(14)

// Calculate exit level based on double ATR
exitLevel = high20Days - atrValue * 2

// Calculate lowest low of the last 10 days
lowestLow = ta.lowest(low, 10)

// Calculate 2 times ATR from the last bar's close
atr2x = atrValue * 2
atr2xClose = close - atr2x

// Condition for entering a long position
longCondition = high > high20Days

// Condition for exiting a long position
exitCondition = low < lowestLow or close < exitLevel or close < atr2xClose

// Calculate additional position size based on ATR
atrPositionSize = atrValue

// Execute long trade entry and add to position
if longCondition
strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long)

// Execute trade exit
if exitCondition
    strategy.close("Long")

// Execute adding to position
if ta.change(close) > atrValue
    strategy.entry("Add Long", strategy.long, qty=atrPositionSize)

// Plot 20-day high and exit level
plot(high20Days, color=color.blue, title="20-Day High")
plot(exitLevel, color=color.red, title="Exit Level")
plot(atr2xClose, color=color.orange, title="2x ATR Close")

// Plot arrows for entry and exit
plotshape(series=longCondition, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, color=color.green, title="Long Entry Arrow")
plotshape(series=exitCondition, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.abovebar, color=color.red, title="Exit Arrow")
```

I got ChatGPT to write me this strategy for TradingView, but it won't generate any orders to backtest. Can I change it so it works? It doesn't put out an syntax-error and there is enough data and paper-money to open positions, so I don't understand where the problem is... thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

It enters a position but never closes it. Because

`low < lowestLow or close < exitLevel or close < atr2xClose`

never becomes `true`.

There are logical errors in this code. `low < lowestLow` and `close < atr2xClose` can never be `true`.

[image]